# Finding a limit using a definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to prove, for $a,b$ positive numbers that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos \left( a + \frac{b}{n}\right) = \cos a$$ by using the definition of a limit. In order to prove this, can I first prove by letting $a_n$ be the sequence which equals $1/n$, where $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$ then prove $a_n \to 0$ as $n$ approaches infinity, then apply this sequence $a_n$ to this equation like $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos \left( a + b\cdot a_n \right) = \cos \left( a + b \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \right) = \cos(a)$$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

Comment: This assumes that cos is continuous and limit can be passed into the function, which in this case, is proving with definition. Try writing it explicitly what you have to show by definition then fill the gaps.

Comment: You cannot prove this if you can't use basic properties such as the limit of $\cos(x)$ to $0$, or equivalents. Or a suitable definition of the cosine.

Comment: The title of the question has little to do with the text.

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach is to use Taylor expansions of sine and consine funtions:

$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$,    $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots$ to prove

$\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x=1$, $\lim_{x\to 0}sin x=0$

Then,

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos \left( a + \frac{b}{n}\right) $

=$ \lim_{n\to \infty} (\cos  a\cos\frac{b}{n}-\sin  a\sin\frac{b}{n})$

=$ \lim_{x\to 0} (\cos  a\cos x-\sin  a\sin x)$

=$ \cos  a  (\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x)-\sin  a( \lim_{x\to 0}sin x)$ (cosine function is continuous)

=$ \cos  a.1-\sin  a.0$

=$\cos a$

Answer (score 1):

That's correct but you should mention why $a_n\to 0\implies \cos (a+ba_n)\to\cos a$. That is because of continuity of $\cos$ function. But let's pretend that we don't know about continuity of $\cos$ function. If $b=0$, we are done so assume $b\ne 0$.

$a_n\to 0\implies \forall \epsilon\gt 0, \exists N\in \mathbb N: n\gt N\implies|a_n|\lt \epsilon/|b|$ 
For $n\gt N$, we also have 
$|\cos (a+ba_n)-\cos a|=2|\sin \frac{a+ba_n}{2}\sin\frac{ba_n}{2}|\le|2 (1)\sin \frac{ba_n}{2}|\le |ba_n|\lt \epsilon$. 
This proves the result by definition.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos \left( a + \frac{b}{n}\right) $$
$$\cos(a+\frac{b}{n} ) = \cos(a)\cos(\frac{b}{n})-\sin(a)\sin(\frac{b}{n})$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \big(\cos(a)\cos(\frac{b}{n})-\sin(a)\sin(\frac{b}{n})\big)$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\dots) = \lim_{\frac{b}{n} \to 0} (\dots)$$
$$\lim_{\frac{b}{n} \to 0} \big(\cos(a)\cos(\frac{b}{n})-\sin(a)\sin(\frac{b}{n})\big)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x) = 0$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(x) = 1$$
$$\lim_{\frac{b}{n} \to 0} \big(\cos(a)\cos(\frac{b}{n})-\sin(a)\sin(\frac{b}{n})\big)$$
$$\lim_{\frac{b}{n} \to 0} (\cos(a)-0)$$
$$\cos(a)$$